# Calculate width of div proportionally to text inside in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've built this no-so-great piece of javascript to calculate the width of a div based on the number of characters by increments.

```
  $(".tweet-text").each(function() {
  var tweetText = $(this);
    if(tweetText.text().length > 30) {
      tweetText.css("width", "200px");
    }
    if(tweetText.text().length > 60) {
      tweetText.css("width", "240px");
    }
     if(tweetText.text().length > 80) {
      tweetText.css("width", "280px");
    }
    if(tweetText.text().length > 100) {
      tweetText.css("width", "310px");
    }
    if(tweetText.text().length > 120) {
      tweetText.css("width", "360px");
    }
    if(tweetText.text().length > 130) {
      tweetText.css("width", "400px");
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to calculate the width of tweetText exactly and proportionally to the number of characters ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not let it just auto width?

Comment: because they're stacked in a carousel and the width is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( '.tweet-text' ).each(function () {
    var $span = $( this ).wrapInner( '<span>' ).children( 'span' );
    $( this ).css( 'width', $span.width() );
    $span.replaceWith( $span.contents() );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/N8xNM/2/

(In my demo, each paragraph is as long as it needs to be, or in other words, as long as its text content.)

Also, set `white-space: nowrap` in CSS on the `.tweet-text` elements.

```
.tweet-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: That's a far nicer approach than my own; I did consider something similar (though possibly less efficient), but made the assumption that the specified increments were required. +1

Comment: @DavidThomas I assumed that the text is most likely *not* monospace, which means that the required width cannot be reliably determined based on the number of letters. Therefore, I had to determine the actual width of the text, and once I had that number, I thought, I might as well just set the width of the container to that value.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you're facing in your code is that every single `if` block will be evaluated; and you're only ever assessing whether the length of the text is greater than a given number, rather than assessing whether the length falls between a given lower *and* upper limit.

To ensure that the `if`s stop being assessed after a given condition matches use `if`/`else if`, and to assess whether the length falls within the lower and upper limits, I've tested for a second condition.

```
$('.tweet-text').each(
    function() {
        var tweetText = $(this),
            strLength = tweetText.text().length;
        if (strLength > 30 && strLength < 60) {
            tweetText.css("width", "200px");
        }
        else if (strLength >= 60 && strLength < 80) {
            tweetText.css("width", "240px");
        }
        else if (strLength >= 80 && strLength < 100) {
            tweetText.css("width", "280px");
        }
        else if (strLength >= 100 && strLength < 120) {
            tweetText.css("width", "310px");
        }
        else if (strLength >= 120 && strLength < 130) {
            tweetText.css("width", "360px");
        }
        else if (strLength >= 130) {
            tweetText.css("width", "400px");
        }
    });​
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P7W3v/1/).